# Cortana will not recognise my USB headset as an audio input device

Tags: usb, windows-10, microphone, cortana

most applications on my windows 10 PC including skype, and chrome will recognise the headset input however, cortana will not recognise any input devices and on the settings > Time & Language > Speech, if I go onto microphone and then click "Get started", it will give me a sample speech sentance. After speaking it it will show me the dialogue box:

[my] microphone is set up
The microphone is ready to use with this computer. Click Finish to complete this wizard

After doing this it seems to have not affected my computer in anyway

PS I have already got my region, speech and language set to: London, English (UK) and English (UK)

Regards

Joe 'Greeneey' Greene

Answer (score 0):

Even though your headset appears to be working in some apps, it sounds like the Windows 10 equivalent drivers are not allowing the proper drivers to install and take precedent causing Cortana to not recognize said headset.

Lets start with the following steps to correct this:

1. To ensure changes to the driver do not occur without your knowledge, open the Control Panel (right-click Start button and select Control Panel)
2. Navigate to System and Security > System > Advanced system settings
3. Click Hardware tab > Device Installation Settings and select No, let me choose what to do option
4. Select Never install driver software from Windows Update
5. Press the Windows key‌ Windows logo key+X and choose Device Manager.
6. In Device Manager, navigate to Sound, video and game controllers
7. Right click on the audio /microphone driver currently installed matching said headset and choose uninstall
8. Ensure the delete the driver software for this device is checked
9. Download and install the latest drivers for said headset
10. Reboot the device
11. Ensure the new drivers are installed and test Cortana ability to recognize the headset